# Change the prediction method in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, predict

I trained my data in tpot, and then I wrote a function to evaluate the best pipeline with different metrics. I want to automize the whole procedure. Tpot will return the best pipeline, and then different metrics will be calculated. The problem is sometimes the optimal model doesn't have "a predict_proba" method like ElasticNetCV or AdaBoostRegressor, then in my evaluation function, I have to divide the two different predictions methods. Something like:

```
if trained_model does have predict_proba:
     do sth
else trained_model does not have predict_proba
     do sth else
```

imagine code like this:
trained_model is the best pipeline from tpot

```
prob_test = trained_model.predict_proba(xtest)
```

if the trained_model is "AdaBoostRegressor", then it returns the error:

```
'AdaBoostRegressor' object has no attribute 'predict_proba'
```

Which it's true. I tried with **while** and **if**, but none of them work. I might be forgetting something here.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `hasattr` to check if the function is there:

```
if hasattr(trained_model, 'predict_proba'):
    return trained_model.predict_proba(...)
# otherwise do something else...
```